# Having trouble using subprocess to automatically search for and change password aging in login.defs

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, scripting

Im trying to create a python script that automatically does a few security checks on my Linux machine. I want to use it for changing PASS_MIN_DAYS  0 in login.defs into a larger number.

Ive already used this code on an isolated .txt file that changed a simple phrase from one string to another but now as i moved to the login.defs it will not work. I am not sure if it has to do anything with the file itself or my code.

```py
def password():
    os.chdir('/etc')
    with open('login.defs', 'r') as file:
        newline=[]
        for word in file.readlines():
            newline.append(word.replace("PASS_MIN_DAYS", "PASS_MIN_DAYS 7"))
            newline.append(word.replace("PASS_MAX_DAYS", "PASS_MAX_DAYS 90"))
            newline.append(word.repalce("PASS_WARN_AGE", "PASS_WARN_AGE 14"))
    with open('login.defs', 'w') as file:
        for line in newline:
            file.writelines(line)
    file.close()
```

There are no error messages included. Also sorry in advance if this is not formatted correctly in any way, this is my first ever post to stackvoverflow :)

Comment: Also at the top of my file it runs sudo bash, so permissions is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```py
subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', '/PASS_MIN_DAYS/c\PASS_MIN_DAYS  7', "login.defs"])
subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', '/PASS_MAX_DAYS/c\PASS_MAX_DAYS  90', "login.defs"])
subprocess.run(['sed', '-i', '/PASS_WARN_AGE/c\PASS_WARN_AGE  14', "login.defs"])

This is the answer that i found that fixes it
```